# Anomolies with git mv, edit then git add

Tags: git

I had a couple of files in my repo and I renamed them both with `git mv`. On doing a `git status`, I see the correct:

```
On branch lnxkrnl-chg123-just-to-annoy-linus
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/lnxkrnl-chg123-just-to-annoy-linus
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    renamed:    file1.service -> RobinHood.service
    renamed:    file1.sh -> RobinHood.sh
```

I then go and edit those files and, as expected:

```
On branch lnxkrnl-chg123-just-to-annoy-linus
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/lnxkrnl-chg123-just-to-annoy-linus'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    renamed:    file1.service -> RobinHood.service
    renamed:    file1.sh -> RobinHood.sh
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   RobinHood.service
    modified:   RobinHood.sh
```

Now, when I actually *add* those new files for staging, one of them seems to be handled intelligently while the other does not. I'll leave it up to the reader how they define "intelligent", suffice to say they appear to be treated differently despite the fact they both had the same operations performed on them:

```
On branch lnxkrnl-chg123-just-to-annoy-linus
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/lnxkrnl-chg123-just-to-annoy-linus'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    file1.service -> RobinHood.service
    new file:   RobinHood.sh
    deleted:    file1.sh
```

The commit change for the service file seems to be a simple rename though I had definitely changed the file content (albeit in a small way, simply changing some of the text on a couple of lines).

The commit change for the shell script (which was edited far more, with many new lines added) is a delete/new operation.

Why does `git` make a distinction here? I would have thought it would make more sense to display something like:

```
renamed & edited:    file1.service -> RobinHood.service
renamed & edited:    file1.sh -> RobinHood.sh
```

But, even *without* that level of detail, I'd expect `git` to treat identical operations in the same manner.

The version of git I'm using is 2.7.4 under Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `pid.service` ... what is this file and why is it appearing in your `git status`?

Comment: @Tim, names were changed to protect the innocent, just not changed suffiently carefully :-) Should be fixed now.

Comment: (And, I edited my answer to remove the `pid.service` name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not actually *know* that files were renamed.  This is true regardless of how you stage and commit a rename, i.e., whether or not you use `git mv`.  What Git does instead—this is true for both `git diff` / `git show` of commits, and `git status` of things you have not yet committed—is to *guess*.

When the *only* thing you have done is to rename some file or files, Git can make a *very accurate* guess.  That is, it will get this right every time.<sup>1</sup>  That's because the *way* it guesses is to look around: "Hmm, I had files `A`, `B`, and `C` before.  I have `A`, `B`, and `D` now.  I wonder ... I know what used to be in `C` before.  Let's see what's in `D` now.  Oh hey, look, what's in `D` now is just what was in `C` before!  I bet the user renamed `C` to `D`!"

But, if you start *changing the contents too*, it gets harder.  In your case, Git sees that `file1.service` and `file1.sh` are both *gone*.  Meanwhile, it sees these files `RobinHood.service` and `RobinHood.sh` are new.  So it compares what *used* to be in all the now-gone files, with what is in all the newly-added files.  None of them match *exactly* any more.  But some of them look suspiciously *similar*.

So, Git computes a "similarity index" for each file-pair.  As it happens, the old (now gone) `RobinHood.service` is "fairly similar" (at least 50%) to the old `file1.service`.  So it picks that pair to call a rename.

Meanwhile, `file1.sh` and `RobinHood.sh` are now so *dis*-similar (below that same 50% similarity requirement) that Git decides those are totally different files.  You must have just removed the first one, and created the second one from scratch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, *almost* every time.  In particular, if you have two identical files `C3` and `PO`, and you rename them to `R2` and `D2`, Git may think you renamed `C3` to `R2` and `PO` to `D2`, or it may think you renamed `PO` to `R2` and `C3` to `D2`.  But if `C3` and `PO` are absolutely, 100%, bit-for-bit identical, why does it matter which old one became which new one?

---

#### `git status` actually runs *two* `git diff`s

This is a bit complicated in `git status` output because `git status` actually runs *two* `git diff --name-status --find-renames` commands internally, one to compare the `HEAD` commit to the index, and one to compare the index to the work-tree.  Until you `git add`, the `HEAD` commit versions exactly match the index versions.  The index versions have different *names* so Git detects these as renames.  Then, the index versions have the same *names* as the work-tree versions, so Git assumes they are the same file (no rename-detecting is required).  It's only when you re-copy the work-tree versions into the index versions, via `git add`, that this two-stage "compare HEAD to index, then compare index to work-tree" falls apart.

For the same reason, if you `git commit` the rename on its own, then `git commit` the modifications, you will, later—by stepping through each commit one at a time—be able to recover, programmatically, the fact of the rename.  If you `git commit` the rename-and-change, Git won't recover the rename later (because it's not recovering it now).

Comment: @torek So are you saying that Git actually compares each renamed file to every file being managed?  This would have the flavor of an `N^2` operation +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: indeed. For this reason, Git (1) prepares a queue of all unpaired files; (2) does a first pass using file hash IDs to find exact matches and pair them and remove them from the queue; (3) tries to reduce the files to chains of "chunk hashes" for the similarity computation; and (4) *limits* the queue size (to `diff.renameLimit`). The built in limit has doubled twice since Git version 1.5.

Comment: There's one more twist: if you run `git diff -B` ("break" rewrites), Git doesn't just say: "oh, there was a file `A` before and there's an `A` now, they must be the same", it runs the same similarity-index test (with pre-test for exact match since that's common and the test is very fast) on that pair. If the result drops below the `-B` threshold, filename `A` goes into the pairing queue.

Comment: Okay, that seems like a viable explanation. Me, I would have though `git mv` would store enough data to be able to figure out what happened without the 50% threshold guess (otherwise, why didn't I just do `mv`?). Still, that doesn't affect the usefulness of the answer. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @paxdiablo `git mv` also stages the removal of the old file and the creation of the new file, whereas `mv` only moves the file without affecting git at all.

Comment: @1615903: right, `git mv` both renames the file in the work-tree *and* "renames" the index/staging-area entry (the latter is a bit complicated as the index is kept in a sorted order so this requires a lot of work internally!).